# How can I convert a date and time into a time only using angular-moment?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

So I have dates like this:

```
$scope.sample_time = "September 14th 2017, 1:00:00 pm";
```

And in my view, I want to only show the time like example `1:00 pm`.

Using `angular-moment`, I tried something like `{{ sample_time | amParse:'HH:mm a'}}` but I get `2017-09-14T06:00:00.000Z`.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"September 14th 2017, 1:00:00 pm"`  is not a default valid date, you need to parse it first, by the corresponding format you use (which is `'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'` ), then you got a valid date and can use amDateFormat to format it: `amDatFormat:'HH:mm a'`

```
{{ sample_time | amParse:'MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a' | amDateFormat: 'H:mm s'}}
```

a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RocNLPq6uBlFnccLFB8N?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

what i do is like this:

```
{{ getLocalDate(sample_time) | date: "hh:mm a"}}
```

get local date converts the current date

```
 $scope.getLocalDate = function (date) {

        return new Date(moment.utc(date));
    }
```

and this outputs the desired time format you want.

Im not sure if this is the best way. I hope this helps

Comment: If you will try that you will get "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. " and a null value.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I think i need to change my implementation. :)